# What US can response to China restriction on rare-earth elements export?

Tags: united-states, economy, china, sanctions

Recently, Nikkei Asian Review [posted](https://asia.nikkei.com/Politics/International-relations/US-China-tensions/China-readies-new-law-to-ban-companies-on-national-security-grounds) an interesting article - the main point is that China is preparing restrictions on rare earth metals to countries opposing China. That is treated as Chinese answer to the western ban on selling semiconductors to Huawei.

What can the US do in response to such law?

Comment: The US is beginning to exploit its own rare earth resources.  Production will ramp and the dependence on foreign supply will shrink.

Comment: Anything from nothing to declare war.

Comment: The "rare" in the name of this group of elements is actually somewhat misleading; the U.S. Geological Survey describes them as "relatively abundant in the Earth's crust." https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dont-panic-about-rare-earth-elements/